# MongoDB - multiple boolean flags or single list of included values?

Tags: mongodb

Which is more accepted practice: making a boolean field for each of multiple (say 3-7) things that could be "on" or "off", or making a single string array field which either contains or does not contain each of the 3-7 things?

Example:

stored -> {green: true, blue: true, red: false, yellow: true}
read -> if collection.find_one(_id).green: // execute code

vs.

stored -> {colors: ['green', 'blue', 'yellow']}
read -> if 'green' in collection.find_one(_id).colors: // execute code

Comment: I don't think there's an accepted practice for this, perse. The first way is faster and scales better, plus it is a more natural model for the situation of setting and checking flags. It's not precisely clear from the question, but if the colors can be any color and not just some fixed set then the second approach is better because it is difficult to work with "data-as-keys" in MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

This is an opinion based question, but anyway, it's way better your second approach assuming that if element isn't found in the array will be configured as false or true (depends on the condition), but that approach is something that I could name [convention over configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration)